# Des livres pour apprendre le francais

Tags: littérature

Salut,

j'aime apprendre le francais. Pour cela, je voudrais lire un livre qui n'est pas trop difficile a comprendre. J'ai deja lu "*Le petit prince*".

Est-ce que vous pouvez recommander un autre livre?

Merci

Comment: Je suppose que ce genre de questions n'est pas approprié pour ce site. Ceci dit, j'ai surtout appris à lire en lisant les Tintin et les Astérix, il y  a longtemps. Et je prends toujours autant de plaisir à les lire.

Comment: Je suis d'accord, mais en même temps, tout comme la personne qui voulait nommer son vin la semaine dernière, ça fait du bien de voir des gens enthousiastes envers notre langue ! En matière de romans, je conseille vivement les différents tomes du Petit Nicolas de René Goscinny, qui sont un joli point de vue de l'enfance (et qui utilisent donc des tournures de phrases assez accessibles).

Comment: I can recommend "graded readers"; see [Where can I find graded readers for French?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/3174/800) on Language Learning Stack Exchange. For other tips, see [Lectures faciles ?](https://francaislangueetonnante.wordpress.com/2014/10/04/lectures-faciles/).

Comment: Merci beaucoup! Je suis désolé. Jje n'ai pas su, que ma question n'est pas approprié.

Answer (score 1):

Bonjour,

Vise les bandes dessinées pour commencer, les livres imagés, les livres que tu as déjà lus dans ta langue de prédilection.

En me basant sur [ce post](https://www.babelio.com/liste/2770/Classiques-de-la-litterature-jeunesse), je te conseillerai :

- La Chèvre de monsieur Seguin
- Moby Dick
- Vendredi ou La Vie sauvage
- Croc-Blanc

mais bon ça dépend de tes goûts.

Le site d'[ila-france](https://www.ila-france.fr/blog/trois-livres-perfectionner-francais) prend le temps d'expliquer comment lire des livres plus complexes.

Enfin, si tu te sens un esprit logique et que tu a pas peur de voir la complexité de la conjugaison française, le "Bescherelle Conjugaison" est un incontournable!

Adishatz!

Edit : oui le petit nicolas aussi comme proposé par Reyedy